# Does unity have a way to get shallow nested GameObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a WallsContainer (parent) GameObject that has many (child) Walls GameObjects in it.

The container has a script attached to it to listen to an event and then check all of the walls. Currently based on the internet I have:

```
foreach (Transform transform in gameObject.transform)
{
    GameObject wall = transform.gameObject;
    // Some Logic with wall...
}
```

This just seems hacky. I understand the logic that everything has a transform. It just does not read well in the code.

I do not need a deep recursive search. I just want to get the objects under my container. Is there any other solution or is this the best I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)

```
List<Transform> transList = new();
GetComponentsInChildren(true, transList);
for (var trans in transList)
    ...
```

or like this

```
for (var trans in GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true))
    ...
```

Comment: Based on this the only way to get a child gameobject from a container gameobject is through the transform? My hang up is using the transform rather then something like `gameobject.getChildren()`.

Comment: Because the parent-child relationship is established through `transform`. A GameObject doesn't contain any parent/child information.